# Using Crystal Reports in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports, activex

I have an Access mdb database that displays a Crystal Report through the ActiveX control in one of its forms. When we were using Office 2010, the Crystal report displayed fine, but after upgrading to Office 2013, the report will not display. There is just a white box where the report should be (no error messages). The report still displays correctly when I open the database with Office 2010.

The form has a Crystal ActiveX Report Viewer Control 10.0 that displays the report. Is there a newer version that we should be using, or are Crystal Reports not supported in 2013?

EDIT:

The reference we have reads: `Crystal ActiveX Report Viewer Library 10.0`.

Comment: While Crystal-Reports-related ActiveX components are referenced in your project?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, but I think that you need to include a reference to the ActiveX control your Outlook project.  Try Tools | References..., scroll the list until you find the control, then select the checkbox.

Comment: Already had the reference.  Removing and re-adding had no effect.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out??

Comment: @Kman -No, I actually gave up and re-wrote the app in C#.net.  Its fairly simple, dropdown box to select which report, then a report viewer.

Comment: Has this been figured out?  I too have an old Access 2000 file that has some code using the older Crystal Report 10 Advanced Developer with the Crystal Reports ActiveX Viewer 10.  I got the code to work in Access 2013, but when showing the report it's just blank.  If I even try adding or working with the OCX in the form design in Access - Access 2013 crashes!  Was there an update to this to work in Access 2013?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem related to win 8.1?
If so, I've found that changes for font types in windows 8.1. will cause problems if you're using Times New Roman.

Changing font should fix your problem (Arial)

Comment: No, wasn't using 8.1.  Problem seems to be with the version of Office in any event.